# Data truncation error (data too long for column item_code)

Tags: java, mysql, updates, truncate

When I update, I get

> data truncation error (data too long for column item_codeat row #)

I'm using `varchar(45)` for `itemcode` in DB.

```
String category="";

String item_code = txt_inventory_item_code.getText();

String item_name = txt_inventory_item_name.getText();

Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = formatter.format(txt_inventory_date.getDate());

String expiry_date = formatter.format(txt_inventory_expiry_date.getDate());

int quantity=Integer.parseInt(txt_inventory_quantity.getText());

double unit_price=Double.parseDouble(txt_inventory_unit_price.getText());


try{
    st = conn.createStatement();
    String SQL = "Update inventory SET "
            + "item_code='"+txt_inventory_item_code+"',"
            + "item_name='"+txt_inventory_item_name+"',"
            + "date='"+formatter.format(txt_inventory_date.getDate())+"',"
            + "expiry_date='"+formatter.format(txt_inventory_expiry_date.getDate())+"',"
            + "quantity='"+txt_inventory_quantity+"',"
            + "unit_price='"+txt_inventory_unit_price+"' WHERE inventory_id Like "+txt_inventory_inventory_id.getText();
    st.executeUpdate(SQL);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Updated Successfully");

}
catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Comment: Post an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Well, the error is that the item code is too long for a varchar(45). You also absolutely need to learn about prepared statements (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), because your code will fail as soon as one of the text fields contains a single quote, and it's subject to SQL injection attacks. they also allow storing dates as dates, rather than having to format them with database-specific, locale-specific formats. And finally, they make the code more readable and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of your code that have some weak points, I recommend that validates the different fields of your model entity, depending on the restrictions that have the corresponding columns on the database table.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are persisting is way too long than expected.
**item_codeat** column in the database expects only strings less or equal to 45 characters.

> Solutions

1 - If you can alter your database. Change the datatype of **item_codeat** to **TEXT**

2- If you cannot alter the database you need to put some kind of validation to restrict clients/users to enter a valid **item_codeat** whose length is less than 45.